# Why does nhibernate add two userIds to the schema?

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys, schema

That's not entirely accurate.  I have a user table and some/most Users are Trainers.  There is a UserRole that specifies if a User is a Trainer or an Admin, and that's the only difference.  Perhaps not the cleanest structure, but often Admins are Trainers too and it works fine.

So I'll have a table like TrainerPayment.  It has a some payment information and a Trainer associated with it which of course is a User.  so

```
public int User Trainer {get;set;}
```

so when I use NH to create the schema I get

```
PaymentName   varchar(250)
PaymentAmount double
TrainerId     int FK
UserId        int FK
```

and then NH uses both of those FK's for different queries.  So for instance, If I do a load(trainerId) it generates sql that looks for userid=2.  And somewhere else it does a query and uses trainerId.  Sorry I forgot where that happened, but I tried to remove the TrainerId and I got an error.  I can look it up if you think it would help.

If it's not clear my question is why do I need both of those FKs ?  It really seems like I should only need one.

Thanks,
Raif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess you have one-to-many on the User that maps to the TrainerPayment? You need to tell that one-to-many that the FK on the TrainerPayment table is called TrainerId, not UserId like the one-to-many will default too.

Comment: I do believe you are right.  still it seems odd that if NH is going to call the UserId that maps to the Trainer TrainerId that it would remember that when designing the related tables.  This could get messy, maybe I need to use the property name User rather then Trainer, or map it make trainer map to a UserId.  well, I'll try this then mark you as correct.  thanks

Comment: Yea, NH really has no way of knowing which FK to use for the bi-directional one-to-many. Sure, it could guess by looking for any User property, but then it's broken if you had more than 1 User property. My guess is the NH team just defaulted to the class name.

Comment: a) yep that worked. Thank you. b) yep that makes sense. c) I guess the only real area of concern is the user table since it's named one thing in the db and another in the model.  The rest of my objects line up much better.  Anyway, thanks for the tip and in retrospect it makes sense.